# how to populate field value of un-related object in salesforce

Tags: apex, custom-object

I have an object(lets say A) which stores couple of values of users using salesforce. A contains fields such as country, year and month.

I have another object(B) which stores last issue date of a country. B also have fields such as country, month and year. B processes last issue date based on country, month and year.

Now, I want this B's last issue date on A object. I knew I can do this when these objects are related to each other(M-D or lookup). But they aren't related to each other.

Is there any way to populate B's last issue date on A based on country, month and Year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to query the B records and update them. For example:

```
List<String> countries = new List<String>();
List<String> months = new List<String>();
List<Integer> years = new List<Integer>();
Map<String, List<B__c>> uniqueComboToBs = new Map<String, List<B__c>>();
// Fill in the lists and the map
List<B__c> bs = [SELECT Id, Field1__c, Field2__c FROM B__c WHERE Country__c IN :countries AND Month__c IN :months AND Year__c IN :years];
for (B__c b: bs) {
    String theKey = b.Country__c + b.Month__c + b.Year__c;
    if (uniqueComboToBs.containsKey(theKey)) {
        uniqueComboToBs.get(theKey).add(b);
    }
}
// Now uniqueComboToBs will contain all B__c records with the given values and you can edit the fields as you wish
```

But beware, that this will be pretty heavy if you have lots of records. Also, think about the data integrity, multiple Bs can exist for an A or vice versa. I would recommend adding some relationship between them.